# How can I make Bootstrap dropdown menu as hover in desktop view and make it clickable in mobile view? How can I avoid hover function in mobile view?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, navigation, responsive

How can I make Bootstrap dropdown menu as hover in desktop view and make it clickable in mobile view? And how can I avoid hover function in mobile view? I achieve this using media query but it creates some issues.